# ReCaptcha hearing quiz is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs, audio, recaptcha

ReCaptcha hearing quiz is not working in IE. The sounds played when selecting play but the download option did not launch a new window or download prompt.
This download and audio is working fine in chrome.
It is calling below api 
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/payload/audio.mp3?

Comment: Include the code that you have done so far.

Comment: Below is code where recaptcha service for MP3 video file is called.<a class="rc-audiochallenge-tdownload-link" target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/payload/audio.mp3?c=0E3QhRfp" title="Alternatively, download audio as MP3"></a> This is working in chrome but not in IE